# Correct use of the WHERE NOT in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table users with 6,169 in it. Some of these users are marked as expired users in a column named 'status' and the remainder have a value of NULL for this column. I'm trying to update the 'status' column for all the users who are still active with the value 'active' however I'm having trouble accurately selecting that group to update on.

When I run

```
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM users;
```

It confirms a 6,169 user count.

When I run

```
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM users WHERE status='expired'
```

It confirms 2,500 expired users. However, when I run

```
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM users WHERE status !='expired'
```

I get count 0. I've tried similar variations

```
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM users WHERE NOT status='expired'
```

and looked at a lot of other StackOverflow questions but can't figure out why my syntax is incorrect. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: you sure you have id with status not expired ?

Comment: should be enough to check wether `status` is different than `'expired'` **or** `status` is null: `... where (status !='expired or status is null)`. Try also using `<>` instead of `!=`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Status is probably a nullable column, and `NULL != 'expired'` is never true.

You could try this:

```
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM users WHERE status IS NULL
```

and it should return 3696. Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e9d53/1).

Answer (score 1):

As you mention in the question, the `status` column takes on `NULL` values.  Any comparison (except `is null`) on a `NULL` value returns `NULL`.  And, `NULL` is considered to be false.  You can think of it as "unknown" rather than "missing", since that can help with the logic.

As you discovered, a `NULL` value fails all of these:

```
where status = 'expired'
where status <> 'expired'
where not status = 'expired'
where not status <> 'expired'
where status = NULL
where status != NULL
```

Remember:  the comparison is `NULL`, not "false".  So, "NOT NULL" is still NULL (because not an unknown boolean is still unknown).  By contrast, "not false" would be true.

The only direct comparison that passes is:

```
where status is NULL
```

To get actives, you would want:

```
SELECT COUNT(id)
FROM users
WHERE status <> 'expired' or status is NULL
```

Or, alternatively, use `coalesce()`:

```
SELECT COUNT(id)
FROM users
WHERE coalesce(status, 'active') <> 'expired';
```

The latter is easier to read.  The previous version has a better chance of using an index if one is available.

Comment: Appreciate the thorough response, fthiella pointed out the same as well and just happened to see that first. Thanks for the extra tip about coalesce()

Answer (score 0):

Select all expired users....

```
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM users WHERE status = 'expired'
```

Select all active users...

```
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM users WHERE status IS NULL;
```

Comment: Based on what the OP is saying, I don't think you want NULL status values for expired users.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it in reverse like that

```
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM users 
WHERE id not in (SELECT id FROM users WHERE status='expired')
```

Answer (score 0):

Possibly try

```
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM users WHERE status NOT IN ('expired')
```

or

```
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM users WHERE status <> 'expired'
```

instead?  Normally I would do these when the column is a number value, I am not sure if it works for a string value.